# Username is replaced with a number when login on Facebook app. Is it a bug?

Tags: facebook, bugs

I logged into Facebook on an Android tablet (on Norwegian language) using Facebook app. And do as usual:

1. Wrote the username and password.
2. Then I click "Log in"

As you can see on the image below, I couldn't login. Instead, a number replaced the username (Probably my UID?). Is this a bug? Where can I report about bugs happens in Facebook app?

[image: a number replaced my username]
(Removed the last 3 digits)

Comment: When you voter down I expect you also manage to write a comment. Not only show that you are completely n00b!

Bug rapotering one of the most important things in the development of applications.

Comment: Are you sure that is the facebook app? Why does the "Log In" button say "Logg inn"? Spelling mistakes like that make me think you are not logging in to the actual facebook app.

Comment: Yes :) "Login" = "Logg inn" in Norwegian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure if you have tried heading over to the Facebook app over the Google PlayStore and have read their description over their you would have got your answer anyway,you can report to the bugs over the [Facebook Help Centre](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/232225526929959).

Note: You need to log yourself over the Facebook account in order to do so.